# Pass the parameters to a page in asp.net without using a gridview

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a HTML Table with a list of items I want to select a row and pass the parameters to a page in asp.net without using a gridview

Here is the table, is this possible?

```
<table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Version
                </th>
                <th>Description
                </th>
                <th>Codeline
                </th>
                <th>BuildStatus
                </th>
                <th>Last Build Date
                </th>
                <th>Owner
                </th>
                <th>ReleaseID
                </th>
                <th>Action
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% if (packages != null)
               { %>
            <% foreach (var item in packages)
               { %>      
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <% = item.BuildVersion %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= item.Description %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= item.Codeline %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= item.BuildStatus %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= item.LastBuildDate %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= item.BulidOwner %> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= item.ReleaseId %> 
                </td>

                <td>
                    select row link here
                </td>
            </tr>    
            <% } %>
            <%} %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a repeater with command name and commandArgumnet.

Comment: @L.Clark I'm glad my answer worked for you, please check my answer as "the answer". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add an id to the row and a click event on the td you want.

```
   function GetData(clickedtd) {
       //id will be row identifier
       var id = $(clickedtd).parent().attr('id');
       var result = "";
       $("#"+id + " > td").each(function () {
           result += "&" + $(this).text();
       });
       //Send request to the server **here!!!**
       alert(result.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ""));
   }


<div>
    <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Version
            </th>
            <th>Description
            </th>
            <th>Codeline
            </th>
            <th>BuildStatus
            </th>
            <th>Last Build Date
            </th>
            <th>Owner
            </th>
            <th>ReleaseID
            </th>
            <th>Action
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% if (packages != null)
           { %>
        <% foreach (var item in packages)
           {/*row id should be unique key*/ %>      
        <tr id= "<% = item.Codeline %>" >
            <td>
                <% = item.BuildVersion %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= item.Description %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= item.Codeline %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= item.BuildStatus %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= item.LastBuildDate %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= item.BulidOwner %> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= item.ReleaseId %> 
            </td>

            <td onclick="GetData(this);">

                select row link here
            </td>
        </tr>    
        <% } %>
        <%} %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```